# Drupal 8 user registration rest api creation step by step

Tags: drupal-8

I am new in Drupal technology. i am trying to create user registration rest API and test on postman. I have tried multiple solution. install rest ui module. enabled registration API changes as per instruction but every time i am failed.

my postman request and response are

```
Request:- 
{
    "name":{"value":"test"},
    "mail":{"value":"test@gmail.com"},
    "pass":{"value":"Pass@123"}
}
```

Response:-

```
{
    "message": "The used authentication method is not allowed on this route."
}
```

Link:- HTTP://localhost/Project_name/user/register?_format=hal_json

Please help me to solved this issue. if possible tell me step by step answer so i can grasp best knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Use this URL to register a user:

```
HTTP://localhost/Project_name/entity/user?_format=json
```